# Redirección modificando el parámetro get en URL, pero que siga accediendo al original

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

No quiero que para el usuario sea visible un parámetro get de una url, pero éste no puede ser eliminado. Me imagino que sea con una reescritura pero no sé cómo hacerlo...

El patrón que tengo hasta ahora solo me redirecciona y lógicamente se rompe en enlace porque no es correcta la url

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)com_component(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1com_nuevonombre%2 [R=302,L]
```

La url que tengo es:

```
http://miweb.com/index.php?option=com_component&view=miseccion&task=comunicacionalusuario&session_id=nm73od0p9b6&session_token=aj0b78h68
```

Necesito que sea (reemplazando `com_component` por `com_nuevonombre`):

```
 http://miweb.com/index.php?option=com_nuevonombre&view=miseccion&task=comunicacionalusuario&session_id=nm73od0p9b6&session_token=aj0b78h68
```

Pero lógicamente que, aún cuando se modifique la URL, siga enviando los mismos parámetros que en la URL original para que no salga error 404. Es decir, que el usuario siempre vea la URL con `com_nuevonombre`, pero que siempre se termine accediendo a la URL con `com_component`.

Comment: Si no querés que sea visible, ¿Por qué lo estás enviando como get y no como post?... Por otro lado, si es necesario que sea get, ¿Por qué no reemplazas `com_nuevonombre` por `com_component` dentro del código de index.php?

Comment: Estoy trabajando con Joomla y es un componente, por lo que tras bastante trabajo (muchos lugares de la web tienen ya parámetro web). Sería demasiado trabajo cambiar todo a post. Y el propio framework es el que lo construye de esta forma, no sé cómo modificar lo del index. Hay manera de hacerlo desde mod_rewrite?

Comment: Es que no sé cómo hacer esa parte del index.php que comentas. Al menos en Joomla no sé cómo abordarlo. Gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estás buscando emparchar sobre otro parche, sin atacar el problema de raíz: por qué estás recibiendo ese parámetro en primer lugar... Si se trata de muchos archivos donde aparece en el código, hay herramientas para reemplazar en varios archivos a la vez.

Es decir, mi primera opción sería corregir todos los lugares donde aparece, o buscar en tu código dónde estás obteniendo el parámetro, que sería algo como:

```
$option = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_principal')->get('option');
```

y modificar el valor de `$option` (o la variable que sea):

```
if ($option == 'com_nuevonombre') {
    $option = 'com_component';
}
```

---

Pero no voy a juzgar tanto tu código, si la idea es seguir emparchando...

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redireccionar para eliminar el parámetro de la URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^((?:.*?&)?option=)com_component([&?].*|$) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1com_nuevonombre%2 [R=302,L]

# Reescribir para que cuando se solicite ?option=com_nuevonombre 
#  en realidad vaya a ?option=com_component, pero de forma transparente
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^((?:.*?&)?option=)com_nuevonombre([&?].*|$) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1com_component%2 [END]
```

La idea es, tal cual estabas haciendo, que si entra con `com_component`, **redireccione** a la misma URL, pero con `com_nuevonombre` en el prarámtero.

Y luego, una 2da regla: ya sea que entre directamente como `com_nuevonombre` o que se haya redireccionado a éste (da igual, es lo mismo para Apache ya que realmente es una nueva solicitud), ahí **reescriba** a la URL con `com_component`.

Una reescritura (a diferencia de una redirección) modifica la URL internamente, pero el usuario no lo ve. Sigue siendo la misma solicitud, pero Apache realiza el cambio internamente.

Para evitar que luego de esto se entre en un loop infinito, yendo de `com_nuevonombre` a `com_component`, y de este último al primero, estoy usando el flag [`[END]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end), que evita que se procesen otras reglas. Sin embargo, dado que es la última de la cadena, hay que tener cuidado en que no se espere que esté actuando ninguna otra regla. Es decir, hay que tener cuidado en cómo es la lógica con el resto de las reglas de tu .htaccess.

Subí este ejemplo a un hosting gratuito si te interesa probarlo:
http://mariano.uphero.com/150759/?option=com_component&view=miseccion&task=comunicacionalusuario&session_id=nm73od0p9b6&session_token=aj0b78h68